# Consolidate Django migrations into a package

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

In my django project I have my migrations being created and applied from each app inside migrations folder, however I need all those migrations to be consolidated and migrated from a saperate package outside my app.

Answer (score 0):

I got this any more suggestions are welcome.

I order to achieve this you need to create a package where package name is not migrations else django will create conflicts.

I created the package ad db_migrations.

Then add this migration folder's reference to your settings similar to below where I have my applications as user and medialibrary:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'user': 'db_migrations.user',
    'medialibrary': 'db_migrations.medialibrary',
}
```

now you can run makemigrations for your app and migration files will be reflected here and  then migrate the same to your db.